# debug android device after alarm

Tags: android

I have my app setting a repeating alarm.  I want to debug in the Eclipse IDE when the alarm wakes up and the BroadcastReceiver is activated.  It seems that once the alarm is set the debug process finishes.  Should the debug breakpoints still be usable after the alarm is set or am I expecting too much?

Comment: I should have added that I am debugging my actual android phone - not the emulator

Comment: i know its too late but just wanted to add that AFAIK even if the alarm is single one or repeating alarm. Activity just sends those alarm in the pending intent and after that there is no executable code. If at all you want to debug you have to put breakpoint in those code which gets executed after the alarm is triggered, which is mostly broadcast receiver or notification code.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late for this, but the way you do it is to add the line:

```
android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
```

in your receiver class **before** the break point.  This will make sure that the debugger is attached before proceeding.